# Passport - Create client credentials grant client programmatically

Tags: laravel, oauth, laravel-passport, clientcredential

The documentation [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens) suggests `php artisan passport:client --client` for creating a client, but I want to do it using a controller, or ideally, using the native JSON apis provided by passport. 
Is that possible at all or will I have to override the methods in `Passport::client` ?

Comment: have you tried `https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question, but here's a 2021 answer for people finding this on Google.

I find calling Artisan commands from code unsavory, especially as @kishore-kadiyala mentioned because you get back printed output, rather than code.

Instead, you can use the Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository class to create a client directly:

```php
use Laravel\Passport\ClientRepository;

// ... snip ...

$clients = App::make(ClientRepository::class);

// 1st param is the user_id - none for client credentials
// 2nd param is the client name
// 3rd param is the redirect URI - none for client credentials
$client = $clients->create(null, 'My Client Name', '');
```

Here, `$client` is a Laravel\Passport\Client instance directly. This is exactly how the Artisan command creates the clients anyway.

Comment: very hepfull!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
Artisan::call('passport:client --client');
```

Look at [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)

Comment: I did look into this but I can't access the values generated using the command using the Artisan Facade

Comment: you know that clients are stored in `oauth_clients` right?

Comment: isn't that enough?